# how do increase my external HDD data transfer speed ? it is transferring the data at 15 MB/sec and sometimes freeze while copying

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

i have 1 TB seagate plus drive just bought using 3.0 I/0 data transfer is extreeley slow and painful. the mountoption is NTFS should i change it to improve the speed ?

Comment: Have you considered possibilities which may be caused by other factors? For example ageing/hardware failure, fragmentation, faulty port etc.?

Comment: The hardware etc aspects described by @pomsky are important. I can add that linux works faster with `ext4` than with NTFS.